# Train a model on a "fleet" of related datasets

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, inference

Suppose I have a machine that has some output behavior y over some independent variable x.  I set up a predictive model to predict the value of y for an arbitrary x and it's working well.

Then I get a second machine which is a lot like the first.  I build a model for this as well.  The models are completely independent.  It works fine, too.  When you examine the data, you see that the machines behave in pretty similar ways -- maybe they both have a linear relationship, but a slightly different slope.  Probably there's a physical variation between the machines.

Maybe my third machine is similar, but I have almost no operating data for it so I can't make a very good model.  I know it will behave similarly to the other machines and I want to exploit this knowledge.

What sort of options exist for modeling $n$ related items as a "fleet"?

Here are some naive ideas:

- Treat all data as one big dataset, i.e. fit one 'average' model for all machines
- As above but add as many additional features as possible that might capture variations across machines
- Cluster the machines into k groups and fit k models
- Use a more sophisticated method which is designed for this type of problem (what options exist?)

If the input data is time-series, does that change anything?

Also, my company is calling this "fleet analytics", is there another name for this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

The classical approach to this kind of problem is a [multilevel model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model). The basic idea is that the parameters of each cluster (machines, in your case) are treated as random variables themselves, coming from one or more higher-order distributions that are common to all the clusters. The practical consequence of using a multilevel model, compared to fitting a separate model for each cluster, is that parameters sharing a common distribution are estimated as being closer together in value.

There's a rich frequentist toolbox for multilevel models, but they also work well with a Bayesian approach; the distributions of the random effects work just like prior distributions.